# React toastify disable backgorund

Tags: reactjs, popup, toast

Can anyone guide me on how to use React toastify callbacks onOpen and onClose disable/blur the background when toast pops up. So that user should not be able to do any click operation or scroll till he closes the toast message.

Comment: I guess you are looking for a modal pop-up ..

Comment: looking for similar on toast msg